# Using a variable to select a class is not working (jquery)

Tags: jquery

Can someone just clear this up for me please ive spent 3hrs looking for the answer and am gonna implode.

I'm trying to get the div with the class inside the toShow variable to slideDown, when I call it statically it works, and alert(toShow) shows the same value as my static selector, but when I use $(toShow) it does nothing:

```js
$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $toShow = $(this).attr('data-val');  

    alert($toShow)                // <======= content1

    $('.content1').slideDown();   // <=====  THIS STATIC SELECTOR WORKS

    $(toShow).slideDown()         // <====== THIS DOESN'T DO ANYTHING
    $toShow.slideDown();          // <======        "
     toShow.slideDown();          // <======        "
    $("." + toShow).slideDown();  // <======        "


});
```

How do i phrase it correctly and use the toShow variable instead of $('.content1')

Comment: Your `data-val` attribute value doesn't appear to include the "dot". Try `$(\`.${$toShow}\`)` or `$('.' + $toShow)`.

Comment: `$toShow.slideDown()` doesn't work because `$toShow` is a string. `$("." + toShow)` doesn't work because your variable name is `$toShow`, not `toShow`. **Voting to close as a typo**

Comment: @charlietfl I don't see anything missing in the question. OP should definitely look in their browser console though as the use of unknown variables like `toShow` will be throwing errors.

Comment: @Phil seeing the actual attribute value would certainly make it more obvious though

Comment: @charlietfl eh, I believed OP when they said `alert($toShow)` displayed _"content1"_ and it fits with the rest of the _problem_